# problem in solving ode with dirac delta function involved

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following second order ODE

$$-y''+y = \delta(t)$$

with $y(0) = y(1) = 0$. For this I wanted to first solve the homogeneous equation $-y''+y=0$ and then applying the fourier transform. The solution to the first can be formed by the characteristic polynomial, i.e. $r^2 = 1$ which leads to the two solutions $y = ae^{t}+be^{-t}$. However, using the constraints it seem at $a=b=0$ which can't be I think. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It usually doesn't  make sense to put the Dirac delta forcing on the boundary. That's because there actually is a solution to the ODE on $\mathbb{R}$ with $\lim_{t \to 0^+} y(t)=0$ and $y(1)=0$. It just isn't zero on $(-\infty,0)$: instead, it satisfies the ODE with $y(0)=0,y'(0)=1$, i.e. the solution on $(-\infty,0)$ is $\sinh(t)$.

Comment: You should find the general solution before implementing your boundary conditions.

Comment: That being said, if you're solving the BVP but looking outside the given interval (not usually how this works, but oh well), then you can follow what I said. You just need a particular solution to the ODE to add to your homogeneous solution, which means some function with $-y''+y=0$ everywhere except $t=0$ and $y'(0^+)-y'(0^-)=-1$. Probably the easiest way to cook up such a thing is actually to solve your problem in the first place, i.e. to use $y(t)=\begin{cases} \sinh(t) & t<0 \\ 0 & t \geq 0 \end{cases}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply Laplace transform to both sides
$$-s^2 \mathcal{L}_t[y(t)](s)+\mathcal{L}_t[y(t)](s)+s y(0)+y'(0)=1$$
Setting $\mathcal{L}_t[y(t)](s)=Y$ and taking in account the initial values we get
$$Y-s^2 Y=1\to Y=\frac{1}{1-s^2}$$
Inverse Laplace transform gives $y=\sinh (t); t<0$.

Comment: $y'(0)$, or rather $y'(0^+)$, was not given. You can use the Laplace transform to arrive at $Y=\frac{1-y'(0)}{1-s^2}$ and thus $y=-(1-y'(0))\sinh(t)$ for $t \geq 0$, so the other BC gives $y'(0)=1$ (since $\cosh(1) \neq 0$), thus $y=0$ for $t>0$. So this solution is not correct.

Comment: @Ian You are right. I edited my answer: do you mind to give a look again?

Comment: It is still not $Y=\frac{1}{1-s^2}$, actually the Laplace transform in the usual sense (integrating on $[0,\infty)$) is just zero. You can exchange the role of $t$ and $-t$ and use the Laplace transform to get that $y=\sinh(t)$ for $t<0$.